# what does @media, @keyframes, @font-face, -ms-flex, -webkit-flex, -moz-something means in css code?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and html, and I have a problem understanding some code in css, those are listed below

```
@media
@keyframes
@font-face
-ms-flex or -ms-something
-webkit-flex -webkit-something
-moz-flex -moz-something
```

can someone explain me what it is, how to use or a link.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Please go throgh the link -https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp ,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp ,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp ,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@media -->  [Mediaqueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) 
@keyframes --> [Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) 
@font-face --> [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) 
-ms-, -webkit-, -moz- --> [CSS Vendor Prefix](https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867)